# DataTables add formatting to cell in numeric column makes column sort as a string not a number

Tags: datatables-1.10

I have a [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) with many columns of numbers. I thought it would be nice to colorize negative numbers so I added a render function, like this:

```
{ data: 'mynumbercolumn', 
    render: function(data, type, row) {
        var x = row.mynumbercolumn;
        if (x < 0)
            x = '<span class="text-danger">' + x + '</span>';
        return x;
    }
},
```

It works in the sense that negative numbers have the text-danger class applied (ie they are in red) but now the column sorts in string order not numerical order, so like this:

```
1
1111
111111
2
222
```

Is there a way to add a class to a cell (or otherwise color negative numbers) in such a way that a numeric column will still sort numerically? If not I'll have to add a custom sort, I guess (or give up on the colorizing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `type` param https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render You return markup in any case, i.e regardless of the `type` is `filter`, `display`, `type` or sort. In this case you only want to return a formatted HTML-string on the type `display`:

```js
render: function(data, type, row) {
  if (type === 'display') {
    var x = row.mynumbercolumn;
    if (x < 0) x = '<span class="text-danger">' + x + '</span>';
    return x;
  } else {
    return data //or row.mynumbercolumn
  }
}
```

A perhaps more elegant way could be to just style the `<td>` itself in a 
[`createdCell`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) callback. Something like :

```js
createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
  if (cellData < 0) {
    $(td).addClass('text-danger')
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome. the createdCell is perfect. Thank you!